# SQL Server slow stored procedure that deletes

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure.
Now I see, that this is very poor performance.
I think this is because of the while loop.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteEmptyCatalogNodes] 
@CatalogId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@CatalogNodeType int = null
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @CID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @CNT int

SET @CID = @CatalogId
SET @CNT = @CatalogNodeType

DELETE cn FROM CatalogNodes cn
LEFT JOIN CatalogNodes as cnj on cn.CatalogNodeId = cnj.ParentId
LEFT JOIN CatalogArticles as ca on cn.CatalogNodeId = ca.CatalogNodeId
WHERE cn.CatalogId = @CID
AND cnj.CatalogNodeId IS NULL
AND ca.ArticleId IS NULL
AND (cn.CatalogNodeType = @CNT OR @CNT IS NULL)

WHILE (@@ROWCOUNT  > 0)
BEGIN
    DELETE cn FROM CatalogNodes cn
    LEFT JOIN CatalogNodes as cnj on cn.CatalogNodeId = cnj.ParentId
    LEFT JOIN CatalogArticles as ca on cn.CatalogNodeId = ca.CatalogNodeId
    WHERE cn.CatalogId = @CID
    AND cnj.CatalogNodeId IS NULL
    AND ca.ArticleId IS NULL
    AND (cn.CatalogNodeType = @CNT OR @CNT IS NULL)
END
END
```

Do anyone of you can give me a hint on how to do it more 'set' like?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT for comments and answers:**

The tables are build like this:

CatalogNodes:

```
CatalogNodeId|ParentId|Name
1|NULL|Root
2|1|Node1
3|1|Node2
4|2|Node1.1
```

CatalogArticles:

```
CatalogNodeId|Name
3|Article1
3|Article2
3|Article3
```

After my SP was called, Node1 and Node1.1 have to be deleted.
In the first delete statement, Node1.1 will be deleted.
In the While loop, Node1 will be deleted.
I hope my problem is now easier to understand, it is a tree structure.

Comment: it's hard to tell without seeing the table indexes/keys

Comment: How many rows are involved totally?

Comment: Consolidate your loop into a single delete statement.

Comment: @betelgeuce thats what I want to do but I dont know how.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Looks like you are trying to delete empty nodes and any parents that contain only empty children?

Comment: What is your expected results from the result of running your stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You just do not need WHILE part as all matched rows will get deleted from the first DELETE statement

Answer (score 1):

your loop doesn't do anything ... the first delete statement will delete a number of records if there are any that comply to your where condition ... so @@rowcount will be greater than 0 but there won't be any records left to be deleted in your second delete statement inside the loop. or did I miss something?

anyway I don't think this executing delete two times in a row has a big influence on the performance ... you should see it if you look at the query plan ...

Comment: I still don't understand why you think that it makes a difference if you execute exactly the same statement with the same parameters a second time ...

Comment: It's a tree structure and the SP deletes leaves. On the first run Node1 is a parent with one leaf, on the second it's an empty leaf that must be deleted

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this in my point is to create a table variable and put all elements that you have to delete there and use i with join to make delete in one single statement.

Answer (score 0):

CatalogNodes is what you want to delete. Create a select that pulls out all the CatalogNodes  you want to get rid of. If there are things tied by foreign key constraints go and delete them first and finally once they are all gotten rid of Delete the CatalogNodes. Temporary tables could be of benefit here as they are held in memory.